# How to get metadata type of function parameters?

Tags: typescript

i can get class constructor parameters types by

```
const types = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target)
```

But how can i get the same for class method?

my class:

```
class SomeController {
  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
  }

  someMethod(user: User) {
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "class method," do you mean `static` method, or prototype method?

Comment: prototype method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata), you'd do that by giving a value for the optional `propertyKey` parameter of `getMetadata`, so:

```
const types = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, "someMethod");
```

Comment: Whether that works with the current [metadata library and TypeScript support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata), I don't know.